# Python String endswith() Method

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list as below and I want to separate out the list based on the string thats ens with

```
list = ['a_balance', 'b_balance', 'a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']
```

expected output

```
list_bal = ['a_balance', 'b_balance']
list_agg_balance = ['a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']
```

I tried below code but `[col for col in list if col.endswith('_balance')]` also includes the elements that endswith '_agg_balance'

```
list_bal = [col for col in list if col.endswith('_balance')]
['a_balance', 'b_balance', 'a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']

list_agg_balance  = [col for col in list if col.endswith('_agg_balance')]
['a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']
```

Comment: 1) `list` is a keyword, avoid using it as a variable. 2) Is there a reason you tagged pandas?

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['a_balance', 'b_balance', 'a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']

lst_agg_bal = [col for col in lst if col.endswith('_agg_balance')]

print(lst_agg_bal)
```

Output:

```
['a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']
```

.

```
lst_bal = [value for value in lst if value not in lst_agg_bal]

print(lst_bal)
```

Output:

```
['a_balance', 'b_balance']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex approach:

```
list = ['a_balance', 'b_balance', 'a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']
list_bal  = [col for col in list if re.search(r'\b(?!agg)[^_]+_balance$', col)]
print(list_agg_balance)
```

This prints:

```
['a_balance', 'b_balance']
```

The regex pattern here works as follows:

```
\b       match word boundary
(?!agg)  assert that what follows is NOT 'agg'
[^_]+    match a single path component
_        match '_'
balance  match 'balance'
$        end of the string
```

For the items ending in `agg_balance`, `endswith` can still be used, because this is the more specific match and won't have false positives:

```
list_agg_balance  = [col for col in list if col.endswith('_agg_balance')]
print(list_agg_balance)

['a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a mask:

```
lst = ['a_balance', 'b_balance', 'a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance']

mask = [col.endswith('_agg_balance') for col in lst]

list_agg_balance = [x for x,y in zip(lst, mask) if y]
list_balance = [x for x,y in zip(lst,mask) if not y]
```

Since you tagged `pandas`, here's a pandas solution:

```
s = pd.Series(lst)

mask = s.str.endswith('_agg_balance')

list_agg_balance, list_balance = s[mask], s[~mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `groupby` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import groupby
import re
key_use =  lambda x: re.sub("^.*?_","",x)
gp = groupby(sorted(lst,key = key_use),key = key_use) #This here contains your answer:
```

Just to visualize it:

```
dict([(i,list(j)) for i,j in gp])
{'agg_balance': ['a_agg_balance', 'b_agg_balance'], 'balance': ['a_balance', 'b_balance']}
```